# Parse list to get new list with same structure

Tags: python, list

I applied a previous code for a log, to get the following list

```
log = ['',
    '',
    'ABC KLSC: XYZ',
    '',
    'some text',
    'some text',
    '%%ABC KLSC: XYZ',
    'some text',
    '',
    'ID = 5',
    'TME = KRE',
    'DDFFLE = SOFYU',
    'QWWRTYA = GRRZNY',
    '',
    'some text',
    '-----------------------------------------------',
    '',
    'QUWERW          WALS          RUSZ                CRORS       ELME',
    'P              <NULL>         R                   98028',
    'P              <NULL>         R                   30310',
    '',
    '',
        'Some text',
    '',
    'Some text',
    '',
    '---    FINISH'
    ]
```

and I want to filter those lines in order to get a list with only the lines that contains "=" and the
lines that are ordered in columns format (those below headers QUWERW, WALS, RUSZ, CRORS), but additionally, for those lines with column format, store
each value with its corresponding header.

I was able to filter the desired lines with code below (not sure here if there is a better condition to filter the lines with columns)

```
d1 = [line for line in log if len(line) > 50 or " = " in line]

d1
>>
[
'ID = 5',
'TME = KRE',
'DDFFLE = SOFYU',
'QWWRTYA = GRRZNY',
'QUWERW          WALS          RUSZ                CRORS       ELME',
'P              <NULL>         R                   98028',
'P              <NULL>         R                   30310',
]
```

But I don´t know how to get the output I'm looking for as follows. Thanks for any help

```
[
'ID = 5',
'TME = KRE',
'DDFFLE = SOFYU',
'QWWRTYA = GRRZNY',
'QUWERW = P',
'WALS = <NULL>',
'RUSZ = R',
'CRORS = 98028',
'QUWERW = P',
'WALS = <NULL>',
'RUSZ = R',
'CRORS = 30310'
```

]

Comment: Why keep working with lists of strings, instead of something more sensible like dictionaries?

Comment: The thing is those parameters are repeated several times in actual data, with different values since the log is pretty large. This is a lot of blocks that begins with a line "ABC..." and ends with a line "--...FINISH". My idea is to have first ordered the data in the same way before to make further analysis. I hope make sense. Th

Comment: It makes more sense to pick a data type that actually benefits the type of operations and analysis you need to perform, and convert the data into that, instead of working with a data type that's uniquely unsuited for the task. Doing what you ask is possible, but you haven't even provided code of your own attempts, and whoever would try to write some would have a needlessly hard job - the problem can easily be solved with other methods. (but you should share whatever you tried regardless)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the `=` is straight-forward.  One way to find the column values might be, as follows, to identify header rows that contain the headings, and then zipping the following rows when splitting by white-space.

```
items_list = []
for item in log:
    if '=' in item:
        items_list.append(item)
    elif len(item.split()) > 3:
        splits = item.split()
        if all(header in splits for header in ['QUWERW', 'WALS', 'RUSZ', 'CRORS']):
            headers = splits
        else:
            for lhs,rhs in zip(headers,splits):
                items_list.append(f'{lhs} = {rhs}')

print('\n'.join(items_list))
```

Comment: It works pretty nice. I had the idea in how to filter the lines with "=", but no idea how to get the lines with columns format. Thanks so much

Comment: may you please explain what does mean and how it works the part inside the `append (f'{lhs} = {rhs}')`

Comment: This is an example of an [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) (aka f-string) in python.  Wrapping the variables in *moustaches* allows you to bring them inside the f-string.